# copy files to destination folder using installshield custom wizard

Tags: c#, winforms, installshield, advanced-installer

i am looking for a way to copy files to some user defined destination folder using installshield installer.
i mean, Installer should ask from the user to provide the destination folder and files should be copied to that folder. it could be a different destination with the installation directory. something like the following image. (this is sample image to give an idea).
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ9jb.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To get helpful answers to your problem you should provide your attempt to solve the issue and point out where you got stuck or where you get an error etc. Here is a link that shows you how to improve your questions on this site. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

It seems Advanced Installer tool has built-in support for your request. The [browse for a folder](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-browse-for-folder.html) article from their UG should help you achieve your requirement.